# Abelian group of order $p^2q^2$ ($p$,$q$ distinct primes) determine number of elements of order $pq$ and $pq^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

Problem

For each abelian group of order $p^2q^2$ determine the number of elements of order $pq$ and the number of elements of order $pq^2$ in $G$.

By the structure theorem we have that

$$(1) \space G \cong \mathbb Z_{p^2} \oplus \mathbb Z_{q^2}$$
$$(2) \space G \cong \mathbb Z_{p^2} \oplus \mathbb Z_q \oplus \mathbb Z_q$$
$$(3) \space G \cong \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_{q^2}$$
$$(4) \space G \cong \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_q \oplus \mathbb Z_q$$

For (4), it is easy to count the number of elements of order $p$ and $q$ in each component, the possibilities are $(p-1,0,0,q-1)$, $(p-1,0,q-1,0)$,$(0,p-1,q-1,0)$,$(0,p-1,0,q-1)$ or the case $(p-1,p-1,q-1,q-1)$. where in each coordinate I've put the number of elements of order $p$ and $q$ respectively. So, we have a total of $(p-1)(q-1)+(p-1)(q-1)+(p-1)(q-1)+(p-1)(q-1)+(p-1)^2(q-1)^2=4(p-1)(q-1)+(p-1)^2(q-1)^2$ elements of order $pq$.

I am not so sure how to count in the other cases, my very first doubt is how elements of order $p$ (order $q$) are in $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ ($\mathbb Z_{q^2}$)?

I would appreciate suggestions to count the elements in the three remaining groups. Am I doing well so far?

Comment: What do you say is the order of $(a,b,c,d)$ in $4$ where none of the components is zero? Note that every element of $\mathbb Z_p \oplus \mathbb Z_p$ except for the identity has order $p$ (think of the non-cyclic group of order $4$ as a model).

Comment: Oops, I forgot about that case, I'll edit it, thanks for the correction.

Comment: For your try: you still have missing terms. Note that you can also have two nonzero elements of order p, and one nonzero element of order q and so on. My answer gives a simpler apporach, but if you actually add all terms it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can write, in each case, the group as $G = G_p \oplus G_q$ where $G_p$ is a group of order $p^2$ and $G_q$ a group of order $q^2$.

In each case, the number of elements of order $pq$ in $G$ is $n_pn_q$ where $n_p$ is the number of elements of order $p$ in $G_p$ and $n_q$ the number of elements of order $q$ in $G_q$.

Likewise, in each case, the number of elements of order $pq^2$ in $G$ is $n_pn_q'$ where $n_p$ is the number of elements of order $p$ in $G_p$ and $n_q'$ the number of elements of order $q^2$ in $G_q$.

The number of elements of order $q^2$ in $Z_{q^2}$ is $\varphi(q^2) = q^2 -q$, where $\varphi$ is Euler totient. The remaining elements, except for the $0$ element, have order $q$, so there are $q-1$.

For $Z_q \oplus Z_q$ the number of elemnts of order $q$ is $q^2-1$ and/as there are (of course) none of order $q^2$.

The remaining calculation should not pose a problem.